# What is the expected timeframe for authentication in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using the built-in Firebase password authentication and I'm wondering what a "reasonable" timeout for logging in via `authWithPassword()`. I had thought initially that this would be sub-second but now it appears there is a lot of volatility and even at 3 seconds I'm getting a lot of timeouts.

> note: I suspect this might not be the highest priority because for typical client app the logging in process is a one-time affair but for micro-services the headroom of 3 seconds is pretty substantial (most operations overall run time is 1-2 seconds). Happy to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly subjective to the app, but Firebase login should be faster than 3 seconds. If you're consistently seeing long times and connection errors, then you should contact support@firebase.com.

You can also let Firebase handle the timeout and/or errors for you in the callback:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
ref.authWithPassword({
  email    : "bobtony@firebase.com",
  password : "correcthorsebatterystaple"
}, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    // this is your login issue
    console.error("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah i think i'll drop firebase a line. I do wrap the **cb** approach that Firebase provides with a promise-resolution strategy which allows me to take advantage of async in many cases but in most cases the authentication is a sync pre-req for other operations.

Comment: Firebase support is always happy to help. The promise strategy shouldn't effect any of the latency you're seeing. You can also try getting a better idea of the timeframes with `console.time()` and `console.endTime()`.

Comment: Let me know if my answer suited your question. If so please mark it as accepted, it's good to keep the unanswered queue clear.